# ruby - How to return from inside eval?

Tags: ruby, eval

I have a code which I need to use within `eval`. Sometimes I need to get out from the eval code, but my tries lead to errors.

E.g.:

```
# expected to see 1, 2 and 5; not 3 nor 4; and no errors
eval "puts 1; puts 2; return; puts 3; puts 4"   # => Error: unexpected return
puts 5
```

I tried with `return`, `end`, `exit`, `break`, and I couldn't get success. `exit` doesn't raise errors, but then I don't get the 5.

(Note: I know that `eval` is evil, but in this case I need to use it.)

Comment: I discovered something weird. `break` jumps out from an `yield`ed block. So, I can do: `def do_yield; yield; end; do_yield { eval "puts 1; puts 2; break; puts 3" }; puts 5` and I get the expected result. I don't know why that works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you all, but I found a solution which fits best into my problem:

```
lambda do
  eval "puts 1; puts 2; return; puts 3; puts 4"
end.call
puts 5
```

This way the intuitive `return` keyword can be used inside `eval` to get out from it successfully.

I didn't like the conditional-like solutions in this case because it would force me (or the user) to add an `end` at the end.

About using `throw/catch` or `break`, I consider the `return` keyword more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

eval'd code is just being run in this place. It's not a function or block. How would you do it without eval? Probably like this:

```
puts 1
puts 2 
if(conditionFor3And4) 
  puts 3 
  puts 4
end
```

Answer (score 3):

you Can't. You can return out of methods, and break out of blocks or loops, but not eval.

You could try a throw/catch block instead

```
eval " 
  should_stop = true
  catch :stop do
    puts 1  
    puts 2 
    throw :stop if should_stop
    puts 3
  end
"
```

or this:

```
  should_stop = true
  catch :stop do
  eval " 
    puts 1  
    puts 2 
    throw :stop if should_stop
    puts 3
 "
 end
```

or just do a conditional like Mchl said, since you probably want it to conditional stop, not just always, but throw catch will let you jump out of a block no matter how many levels down you are, which make it more robust, if you need to break out of a nested loop or something like that.

Comment: Awesome answer! This way I can put `catch :stop do ... end` __around__ `eval` and use only the `throw` inside it! Before your answer, I was thinking about using `Continuation`, but `catch/throw` is by far better because it doesn't involve cc global variables, only symbols.

Comment: I Didn't realize that but that's cool, you can put them out side of eval block. Whoa.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use conditionals instead of early returns.

Answer (score 0):

You could quite happily define a function and execute it last at the end of the script as follows:

```
def ev(s)
  eval("def doStuff()\n" + s + "\nend\ndoStuff()")
end

ev("
    1
    return 2
    3
")

#=> 2
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/CoolLightheartedSoftwaresuite)